# Custom font is having problems in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, fonts

Here's the top of my style sheet:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Open Sans'), local('OpenSans'), url(https://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/opensans/v6/cJZKeOuBrn4kERxqtaUH3T8E0i7KZn-EPnyo3HZu7kw.woff) format('woff');
}
body{
    font-family:"Open Sans";
    background-image:url(images/greyFadeBG.jpg);
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    height:100%;
    min-width:870px;
    font-size:14px;
    color:#666666;
}
```

This displays the custom font in IE(9 and 10)
If I change the line from font-family:"Open Sans"; to font-family:"Open Sans", sans-serif;

The custom font will show in IE7, but all IE version will show the san-serif font.

I've tried this from Font Squirrel with no luck:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'open_sansregular';
    src: url('opensans-regular-webfont.eot');
    src: url('opensans-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('opensans-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('opensans-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('opensans-regular-webfont.svg#open_sansregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `@font-face` is not supported in IE8 and lower and IE9+ only support extensible open type (.eot) fonts.

Comment: @jimjimmy1995, IE was the first browser to support `@font-face` (in version 5.5), and IE 9 added support to formats other than EOT; see http://caniuse.com/fontface

Comment: So what is the problem? IE 9 supports WOFF format, IE 8 does not. To make the downloadable font (“custom font”) work on all browsers, use alternative font formats as shown in the FontSquirrel code. But naturally you must use the same name for the font there as in your `font-family` declaration for `body` or other elements. You should explain exactly how you tried the FontSquirrel way (full code of a demo).

Answer (score 0):

for the second `@font-face` to work you'll need to change the body font-family to

```
body{
    font-family: "open_sansregular";
}
```

or better yet

```
body{
  font-family: "Open Sans", "open_sansregular", sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: That helps! I just had to add the sans-serif at the end to make it work :font-family:"Open Sans","open_sansregular", sans-serif;